# jhipster 500 connection error but I can sign in but I can't see entities

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, mariadb, jhipster

so I cloned this jhipster project that a senior dev made. it's pretty empty he only added an entity called product using a csv file.
after spending a whole day to configure database server port. i got it working.
so now I can sign in as admin and find the metrics for performance, api and everything.
but when I click entities/products the app throws a 500 connection error.
I am unfamiliar with how mariadb works but I installed it

possible reasons for this behavior:

- I didn't configure any classpath when installing java/jhipster
- I don't manually start the mysql server but the ports are configured
- I didn't run any jdl command it was already ran in another pc before cloning
  I expect to see the products table when clicking entities/products

Comment: when I got to the administration/api section in jhipster app and execute get request for products, it returns this message:

Comment: {
  "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet",
  "path": "/api/products",
  "message": "error.http.500"
}

Comment: Have a look at the java app logs, there must be an exception that is the cause of the http 500, itg's not something that  you can see in client.